# Software to provide server alias for server which is behind VPN

Tags: vpn, dns, utility

I once found a small utility that ran on windows and as my public IP address changed (as it will under VPN), the utility would update a record mapping that to a public domain alias. So this website gave me an alias like:

```
toddmo.whatwebsitedoesthis.com
```

and I could point my clients to that domain, and the windows utility would (call an API on that website I guess) every time my public IP changed so that the alias always worked.

Comment: Are you referring to DynDNS? https://dyn.com/remote-access/?_bt=231619788367&_bk=dyndns&_bm=e&_bc=969788846&_bn=g&LS=PPC&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2pXXBRD5ARIsAIYoEbfW7Qz_dFVy6wcd4-0_O5iAkKKQ6Ws9--U1go_9o29e-MA5Q4ntm0MaAtuXEALw_wcB

Comment: @Sonamor looking at the self-answer: Obviously :) Though not specifically the one you've linked to, but rather the general feature of [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS).

Comment: @Izzy, before I asked this, I didn't check to ensure my service would work with just the IP address given by the VPN. It doesn't. It only works when VPN is turned off. So, VPN issue. I'll have to get that resolved before I can avail myself of dynamic dns.

Comment: @toddmo OK, but that's a different issue (for a different SE site). What you asked for was a dynamic DNS service, right? Though even if, I'm not sure that would be considered "software" unless you want to host it yourself, which would need a machine with a fixed IP.

Comment: I may post my VPN issue on SuperUser. Or I may buy a VPS and host my service on the same machine as my website. I'll figure that out in the next week or so. Thanks for your help! If you don't close the question, I'm sure I'll return here to my own question and answer in 2 years from google, having forgotten again what it is /s

Comment: The question should be closed as it's not about software, but a service provided by others such as dyndns or noip.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's a website called https://www.noip.com

Comment: Hello toddmo, please mark this answer as _Accepted_ so the question is closed